# How can i pass test varible to component how to pass in astro js

Tags: astrojs

I am trying to create a simple website with Astro but came across this problem. Whenever I try to pass a JS variable test from sript into HTML, the structure breaks. The last container is moved into the container before it

I am trying to create a simple website with Astro but came across this problem. Whenever I try to pass a JS variable test from sript into HTML, the structure breaks. The last container is moved into the container before it
I am expecting to update scirpt inside varible to component

Comment: ---

---

<div
    id="gg"
    class="top-[50%] left-[50%] fixed z-50 h-full w-full flex justify-center items-center hidden"
    style="transform: translate(-50%, -50%); background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);"
  >
    <component
      imgOne="/images/yellow_diamond.png"
      imgTwo="/images/yellow_diamond.png"
    />
  </div>

<script>
   let test="Helo"
</script>

my code

Comment: please edit your question with a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example